# Obtener duración de video con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Necesito obtener la duración total de un video (HTML5) con JavaScript, he buscado por todos lados y no encuentro nada, probé con este:

> var Duracion = $("#mivideo")[0].duration;

Pero no funciona, muestra **"NaN"**

Este es mi fragmento de video HTML:

```
<video id="frame"
    src="blob:mivideo.mp4"
    autoplay controls preload="auto">
    Tu navegador no implementa el elemento <code>video</code>.
</video>
```

En el src agregué el "blob" como referencia de que estoy usando blob.

Si conocen un método que cumpla con la tarea que necesito les agradezco sus comentarios y respuestas, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Y el fragmento HTML que carga el video, cómo está definido?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/duration

Comment: @Alfabravo Listo amigo ya edité

Comment: @Samsepi revisa el enlace que te pasé